# Using an existing sqlite3 database with django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am getting started with Django and have this particular question regarding using my own SQLite database with Django. What I mean is that if I create a new database and populate it everything works fine. Here is my situation now.

I have an existing database in my instance retail_data.sqlite3 in the BASE_DIR. I now want to use this as the data so I go ahed and add this to seettings as follows.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },

    'retail_data':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME':os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'retail_data.sqlite3')

    }
}
```

The above piece of code is replicated from [this site](https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2017/03/21/using-django-with-an-existinglegacy-database/). 
I then use the inspectdb command (python manage.py inspectdb --database=retail_data > salesapp/models.py) to generate the models.py which can use my current database. Also I go ahead and update the admin.py file so that I can see it from my admin panel. In the admin panel however even though the data table is visible I am unable to view the data.

I was in doubt as to if the database actually consisted data so I used simple pandas.read_sql_query to query the data base and it has all the required data. How should I proceed? Your guidance is much needed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to tell Django which models use the database you've named `'default'`, and which models use the database `'retail_data'`.

You do this by writing [a database router class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers).

Comment: HI James, I have done that too But I get the same result. The database has data but it does not show up in the admin